# Как склоняются географические названия : на -ое славянского происхождения?

Tags: склонение

Вот смотрю правила: Склонение на -ово, -ёво, -ево, -ино, -ыно  - с ними все ясно... А остальные окончания?

Comment: и правило у Розенталя подскажите?

Comment: Отметьте полезный ответ галочкой, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Географические названия в сочетании с родовым словом обычно не склоняются в следующих случаях:

•   когда внешняя форма названия соответствует форме множественного числа: в городе Великие Луки;

•   когда род обобщающего нарицательного слова и топонима не совпадают: на реке Енисей (однако это замечание не относится к сочетаниям со словом город, поэтому правильно: в городе Туле, из города Москвы; о целесообразности употребления здесь самого слова город см. ниже).

Приложения-топонимы среднего рода, оканчивающиеся на -е, -о(кроме географических названий на -ово, -ево, -ино, -ыно, о них речь отдельно), не склоняются:

из города Видное. Правильно: в Видном, из Видного, но: в городе Видное, из города Видное; в Великих Луках, но: в городе Великие Луки.

http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=bc1c9e6e-c0b5-4df1-8760-b03ea114851b

Comment: т.е. все склоняется, кроме вышесказанного. Ясно!